# Conditional Probability Given multiple independent events, Calculate P if possible

Tags: conditional-probability

I am having difficulty in starting this question/which formula would be best to use and how would i be able to get the events as finite intersections.

The questions is:
**P(A1 ∪ A2|A2 ∪ A3) = 5/6.**
Determine the probability, assuming A1-A5 are independent events.

So far i have:
P(A1|A2)*P(A2|A2)*P(A2|A3)*P(A1|A3)=5/6

P(A1∩A2|A2)*P(A2∩A3|A3)**P(A1∩A3|A3)*P(A2∩A3|A3)=5/6

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Determine what?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the Comment on Syntax , my apologies. Kavi, trying to find: Determine the probability p (if it exists), given the following conditioned
probability.